# std::unordered map of string - function pairs

Tags: c++, stl

I need to map a set of functions (functions from the `mpfr::real` library) to a set of tokens but I don't know how to directly map the tokens to functions. How do I do this?

Comment: obviously, for each mpfr function, I write a new functor.

Comment: How about storing the functions directly? What you've written is not valid C++.

Comment: That's what I don't understand how to do.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? What kind of program are you writing? What do you expect to *do* with the functions (once you've stored them in your map)?

Comment: I want to make a parser for a calculator that converts a set of tokens to RPN and then, based on the operator (+. -, sin(), etc) executes the appropriate function on the 2 operands. So, I need to map the mpfr functions to string tokens.

Comment: Well... std::unordered_map<TokenType, std::function<OperandType(OperandType, OperandType)>> is what I'd go for as a first attempt. This ofc assymes that all operands are of the same type which may or may not be the case. And from a glance at mpfr::real wrapper probably not. The return and parameter types are part of the function signature in C++ and cannot be discarded. You could write  functors that provides overloads for every type you want to support, ofc, and use std::unordered_map<TokenType, FunctorType>.

Comment: So I would have to write a bunch of unique functors for this?

Comment: It depends on the types your operands can be (as their type(s) will "carry over" into the signatures of the functions you want to run). If every operand is `mpfr::real<1024>` and your tokens are `std::string` then you could ostensibly use `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<mpfr::real<1024>(mpfr::real<1024>,mpfr::real<1023>)> ops;` and for instance store lambdas that do the work: `ops["add"] = [](const mpfr::real<1024> a, mpfr::real<1024> b) { return a + b; };`

Comment: I've implemented this as a set of functors corresponding to each function(The args to operator() are changed accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

I am now defining functors like this using `#define`-

```
#define op(opname, ret, argtype, fn, args...) struct opname { ret operator ()argtype { return fn } };
```

Which lets me write(for example)-

```
op(add, real, (real a, real b), mpfr::operator +(a, b))
```

(real is typedef `mpfr::real<1024>`)

to get-

```
struct add { real operator ()(real a, real b) { return mpfr::operator +(a, b) } };
```

So that I can quickly write functions for all types.